# Why passed value from ng-controller is blank in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

I have made one plunker of my existing code , where I want to search the user query into the database. I can do `$https` call n all, its just that the data from one controller (from `setSearch` to `getSearch`) to the other is getting lost somewhere. I have user services to pass the data

http://plnkr.co/edit/ncSSFlG1YcwAMmpl9WDX

I am facing issue on below code:

```
app.controller ('getSearch',function($scope,queryService){

 var userQuery= queryService.getUserQuery();
 alert(userQuery); // why is it blank?????????????//

 // i want to make a https call using this userQuery and fetch data from DB

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your button is of type submit, and the form has no action to it so the page just refreshes when you click it. When the page refreshes, everything is reset and you lose the data.

I changed your button to be `type="button"` which does not submit, and manually changed route after you click the button just so you could see that the data is stored and passed correctly.

```
$scope.getQuery = function(message){
   queryService.setUserQuery(message);
   $location.path( "/search" );
};
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/elyGdwWyU6B77lCQifdF?p=preview)

Comment: There is still one small issue in ur code, Your search code only works once. Try putting some text the second time, it never goes to `getSearch` controller

Comment: @Shashank I didn't try to fix your design. It happens because you're on the `search` state, therefore the location.path does not change routes and the controller is not reloaded.

Comment: ohh.yes. I figured that out. any suggestions? or else i'll have to google it out :(((

Comment: Umm that depends on what exactly you want to do. You need the 2nd controller informed when the value changes ? If so, that means communication between controllers --> you need to use a service to hold that data.

Comment: ok, u mean apart from `app.factory ('queryService')` , u want to create another service ? i want `searchResult.html` to load searched data, so need to call `getSearch` on every click.

Comment: It can be the same service, you can save the search term there, and have in your 2nd controller: `$state.$watch(function () { return queryService.searchTerm; }, function (newVal) { // do stuff });` It will trigger every time it changes.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this though, since every letter change it will trigger and you probably don't want that. Instead you might want to think why you want the 2nd controller to know when the value that's in the scope of the first controller changes. You probably want to handle it in the first controller (that what I'd have done)

Comment: adding `$route.reload();` after `$location.path` did the trick. :)